No significance in omnibus test, but significant in EMM
I am trying to investigate the difference between the level of a protein in people with and without an injury.
The protein is a transformed variable, and normally distributed. I wanted to adjust for age and sex of the participant as these can both effect the level of protein.
I thought the best approach would be an ANCOVA, with age and sex adjusted means (EMM) and comparison between these. The omnibus test result was non-significant between the groups, however comparison of the EMM created from the ANCOVA is significant. I was wondering how to interpret this?
